Extend TenantResolveContributorBase
I'm working on ABP framework and I'm trying to extend the TenantResolveContributorBase to extend the tenantId functionality; I want to work also with OrganizationId on my Domain project as:
Desired result: use of OrganizationId as how the tenant works; all queries should be filtered by this column
I created CustomOrganizationTenantResolveContributor on Domain module
public class CustomOrganizationTenantResolveContributor : TenantResolveContributorBase
{
    public const string ContributorName = "CustomOrganizationTenant";

  public override string Name => ContributorName;

    public override Task ResolveAsync(ITenantResolveContext context)
    {
        var organizationId = context.HttpContext.Request.Headers["OrganizationId"];
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(organizationId))
        {
            context.Handled = true;
            context.TenantId = Guid.Parse(organizationId);
        }
        
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}

But this is throwing errors:

ITenantResolveContext does not contain a definition for
HttpContext...
ITenantResolveContext' does not contain a definition for 'TenantId'
and no accessible...

How can I get the correct HttpContext or achieve the desired result? Has anyone done that before?

https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/Multi-Tenancy#abpaspnetcoremultitenancyoptions. Here, it shows how to do what you want with the option.
services.Configure<AbpAspNetCoreMultiTenancyOptions>(options =>
{
    options.TenantKey = "OrganizationId";
});


Additional Sources:
https://github.com/abpframework/abp/blob/bfa5d76fe8c6422e416c62d763edb98e831223f8/framework/src/Volo.Abp.AspNetCore.MultiTenancy/Volo/Abp/AspNetCore/MultiTenancy/HeaderTenantResolveContributor.cs#L24
https://github.com/abpframework/abp/blob/dev/framework/src/Volo.Abp.AspNetCore.MultiTenancy/Volo/Abp/AspNetCore/MultiTenancy/TenantResolveContextExtensions.cs#L11

Hello, but what if I don't want to replace/change the tenant? I want to add another one. Will this remove the actual tenant, or will both work?

I don't quite understand. Can you be more specific?

So, all my applications work with tenantId, and I want to keep that functionality, but now I want to EXTEND no change to work with OrganizationId; will this replace my current tenantId functionality on all my entities, or will it work with both?

it doesn't extend, it just changes it. So I added a 2nd answer and edited your code in this answer.

public class CustomOrganizationTenantResolveContributor : HttpTenantResolveContributorBase
{
    public const string ContributorName = "CustomOrganizationTenant";

    public override string Name => ContributorName;

    protected override Task<string?> GetTenantIdOrNameFromHttpContextOrNullAsync(ITenantResolveContext context, HttpContext httpContext)
    {
        if (httpContext.Request.Headers.IsNullOrEmpty())
        {
            return Task.FromResult((string?)null);
        }

        var tenantIdKey = "OrganizationId";

        var tenantIdHeader = httpContext.Request.Headers[tenantIdKey];
        if (tenantIdHeader == string.Empty || tenantIdHeader.Count < 1)
        {
            return Task.FromResult((string?)null);
        }

        if (tenantIdHeader.Count > 1)
        {
            Log(context, $"HTTP request includes more than one {tenantIdKey} header value. First one will be used. All of them: {tenantIdHeader.JoinAsString(", ")}");
        }

        return Task.FromResult(tenantIdHeader.First());
    }

    protected virtual void Log(ITenantResolveContext context, string text)
    {
        context
            .ServiceProvider
            .GetRequiredService<ILogger<CustomOrganizationTenantResolveContributor>>()
            .LogWarning(text);
    }
}

